# How do I write a decorator to wrap something in a context manager, that takes parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators, pyro

I've seen [How to use a context manager inside a decorator and how to pass an object created in decorator to decorated function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30339510/1075247) as well as [python decorators with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5929165/1075247), and I'm trying to combine the two..but I'm struggling to get my head round it.

I'd much rather use the func tools `@wrap` decorator to do this if possible, as I know if will preserve the doc string.

What I want to do is this:

```
def pyro_opener(func,service,database,port,secret_key):
    def wrapper(params):
        with Pyro4.Proxy("PYRO:"+service+"@"+database+":"+port) as obj:
            obj.set_secret_key(secret_key)
            return obj.func(params)
    return wrapper


@pyro_opener(output_service, employee_db,port=9876,secret_key="h3llow0rld")
def get_employee_names(salary):
    return obj.return_employee_names(salary)  # obj is clearly not in scope here
                                              # but what else can I do?


get_employee_names(25000)

>>>> Bob, Jane, Mary
```

I don't think this works this way, the method `return_employee_names` is on the service at the other end of the connection. Should I just return the function call? If so how do I pass the params in then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd pass in the object bound to with `with ... as` to the wrapped function; the function would *have* to accept such an argument.

This is analogous to how methods work; they are just functions with an extra first argument (`self`) passed in:

```
def pyro_opener(service, database, port, secret_key):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            with Pyro4.Proxy("PYRO:{}@{}:{}".format(service, database, port)) as obj:
                obj.set_secret_key(secret_key)
                return func(obj, *args, **kw)
        return wrapper
    retutrn decorator

@pyro_opener(output_service, employee_db, port=9876, secret_key="h3llow0rld")
def get_employee_names(obj, salary):
    return obj.return_employee_names(salary)
```

Note that I had to add another nested function in the `pyro_opener()` to make it a proper decorator factory.

Comment: So when I call `get_employee_names` where do I get the obj param from? Also, I thought that using `@wraps` mean I wouldn't need the extra level of decoratoryness...?

Comment: @Pureferret: look closely at my version of `get_employee_names()`; the `obj` argument is *explicit*. `functools.wraps()` has nothing to do with decorator factories, and everything with copying metadata across from the wrapped function to the wrapper, so that the latter looks more like the original.

Comment: @martjinpieters what I mean is,  when I want to use ` get_employee_names` I need to supply the obj  parameters (just line I need to supply salary). I can't as ñ call the method like so `get_employee_names(???,300000)` but what do I put in for the `???` ?

Comment: You don't; the *decorator wrapper* passes in that argument. Just like calling a method on an instance, where `self` is supplied for you by Python.

Comment: Look closely at how `wrapper()` calls `func()`.

Comment: *Right*, good analogy with self. I would have called that... Implicit,  I guess?  I'm used to all parameters for a method coming from the same place....except `self`...thanks.  once I've tested it tomorrow I'll check the accept mark.